# closure of separative quotients

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, order-theory

Does there exist a partial order, nontrivial for forcing, that is countably closed, but whose separative quotient is not countably closed? Supposing the answer is yes, then is there a partial order, nontrivial for forcing, that is countably closed, but is not forcing equivalent to any countably closed separative partial order?

For those of you unfamiliar with the separative quotient of a partial order, it is defined as follows. Two elements of a partial order are compatible iff there is some element below both of them. We form the separative quotient of a partial order by taking equivalence classes: x is equivalent to y when x and y are compatible with the exact same things. We then define a new partial order for the separative quotient -- $x \leq y$ iff everything compatible with x is compatible with y.

A partial order is said to be separative if whenever $x \nleq y$, there is $z \leq x$ such that z is incompatible with y. The separative quotient of any partial order is separative.

Some of the ways, order-theoretically speaking, that two partial orders can be forcing equivalent are

(1) They are isomorphic, or more generally,
(2) A dense subset of one of them is isomorphic to a dense subset of the other.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Norman! I added the 'forcing' and 'order-theory' tags to your question. Also, since it seems, in principle, that this question might be answerable by someone outside forcing---it is at heart a combinatorial question about partial orders---I would recommend that you might explain a bit more about what you mean by 'separative quotient' and indeed 'separative', in order to assist this possibility.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about adding the forcing tag, but it only had one other occurrence so far, and the site suggests not creating new tags. 

Comment: You need 250 reputation to create tags. But it is encouraged to use all the appropriate tags that do exist, and I had created the forcing tag for precisely this sort of question. I believe that as MO grows enormous, the tags will play an increasingly critical role for people to find the questions that might interest them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stevo Todorcevic answered this question for me at the MAMLS conference in honor of Richard Laver last weekend in Boulder, CO. Apparently, the answer is that examples of forcings that are closed, whose separative quotients are not closed, come up frequently, with one particular example being forcings involving semi-selective coideals studied by Ilija and Farah.

Comment: I think you mean Ilijas Farah.

Comment: But can we have the details?

Comment: Yes, it must have been Ilijas Farah. I have a handwritten name in my notes, so it was hard to transcribe. I didn't get any details, though, and was unable to find the work online after a quick search.

Comment: Have you looked at #43 on Ilijas's home page http://math.yorku.ca/~ifarah/preprints.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a definite answer for either question, but here are some facts that may be useful (mostly for the second one) though you may be aware of them already.

If $P$ is countably closed then the complete Boolean algebra $RO(P)$ is strategically closed. So, by a result of Boban Velickovic (*Playful Boolean Algebras*, TAMS 296, 1986), if $RO(P)$ has a dense subset of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ (e.g. when $|P| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$), $RO(P)$ must have a countably closed dense subset. Another result of Matt Foreman (*Games Played on Boolean Algebras*, JSL 48, 1983) shows that if $RO(P)$ is $(\kappa,\infty)$-distributive and has a dense set of size $\kappa$, then $RO(P)$ has a countably closed dense subset. This puts some constraints on potential counterexamples.

Also Jech and Shelah (*On countably closed complete Boolean algebras*, JSL 61, 1996) contains a potentially inspirational example, and Bernard König (*Dense subtrees in complete Boolean algebras*, MLQ 52, 2006) shows in more detail what to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is a non-atomic poset that is $\kappa$-closed forces that $|P|=\kappa$, then the separative quotient of $P$ is equivalent to $\mathrm{Col}(\kappa,|P|)$.  This can be shown using the folklore argument about collapses presented as Theorem 14.1 in Cummings' article in the Handbook of Set Theory.

We sketch the argument for $|P|>\kappa$; the other case is similar.  To show this, first let $\dot f$ be a name for a surjection from $\kappa$ to the generic filter $\dot G$.  Inductively define a tree in $P$, where at successor $\alpha+1$ stages we split into a maximal antichain $A$ of size $|P|$ below the previous node and for every $p \in A$, $p$ decides $\dot f(\check\alpha)$.  (We can find such an antichain because the forcing is nowhere $|P|$-c.c.)  At limit stages we use $\kappa$-closure and select  maximal antichains below the given descending chains (or take inf's if they exist).

The tree is clearly order-ismorphic to a dense subset $D \subseteq \mathrm{Col}(\kappa,|P|)$.  Let $\pi : D \to P$ be the map.  This is in the original order $\leq_P$, which may not be separative.  Let $\preceq$ be the order on the separative quotient, i.e. $p \preceq q$ when all $r \leq_P p$ are compatible with $q$.  This extends $\leq_P$, so the tree is order-embedded into the separative quotient as well, by $d \mapsto \pi(d) \mapsto [\pi(d)]_\preceq$.

Finally we claim that the image of $D$ is dense in the separative quotient.  If $p \in P$, then there is some $q \leq p$ and some $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $q \Vdash \dot f(\check\alpha) = \check p$.  There is some $r$ in the $\alpha+1^{st}$ level of the tree compatible with $q$.  Since $r \Vdash \dot f(\check\alpha) = \check t$ for some $t \in P$, we must have $t = p$.  Thus $r$ forces $p$ to be in $\dot G$, and therefore $r \preceq p$.